# Android Density Independent Pixel Drawables Resource Folder

Tags: android, opengl-es2

I'm trying to get to grips with DIP in Android (using Eclipse). I'm writing a little game with OpenGL ES 2.0. Could I get some guidance and tips on what I'm not understanding/doing right.

From what I understand I need to make different sizes of the same image so that they appear correctly on different devices. This is because each device has a different aspect ratio and a 1cm by 1cm sprite on one screen might not be 1cm by cm on another screen.

I read [here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android) that I need to place my sprite images in the res/drawables folders. I did this, but when I try to reference the resource using:

```
    mySpriteTexture = new Texture(context, R.mysprite);
```

the R class fails to find the .png. I have tried cleaning, rebuilding etc., and tried variations like R.res.mysprite. Although I don't see the point in trying R.res.drawables-XXX as according to the article Android is meant to pick the correct images on running...

I think it must be something to do with the XML manifest? But I have no clue. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `R.drawable.myprite`. Android will choose the correct size image from those available in the drawable-XXX drawers.